# Const function specification in UML

Tags: c++, uml

If I have fnc:

```
class AClass
{
    void fnc() const;
};
```

Am I supposed to provide const modifier in UML class diagram while listing this fnc or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are the only person who will identify your UML Diagrams details. So UML does not dictate(if it dictate who cares:-)) you anything... You can show it or not .

The real question is:

> Why you draw that diagram? Who is your audience? [ Who will read diagrams]

and

> For yourself or for your audience, is it necessary show that detail? What kind of benefit you gain?

**Just technical info**

In c++

> Declaring a member function with the const keyword specifies that the function is a "read-only" function that does not modify the object for which it is called.

So ...

> If fnc does not change anything on it ( it can change on Logger) It can be "labeled" as "query".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed looking for the **isQuery** property on an **Operation**.

According to the UML (2.5) specs:

> If the isQuery property is true, an invocation of the Operation shall not modify the state of the instance or any other
>   element in the model.

With regards to the notation UML says the following:

> `[<visibility>] <name> ‘(‘ [<parameter-list>] ‘)’ [‘:’ [<return-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’][‘{‘ <oper-property> [‘,’<oper-property>]* ‘}’]]`

where

> `<oper-property>` indicates the properties of the Operation.
>
> `<oper-property> ::= ‘redefines’ <oper-name> | ‘query’ | ‘ordered’ |‘unordered’ | ‘unique’ | ‘nonunique’ | ‘seq’ |‘sequence’ |<oper-constraint>`

So for you example that would become

`+ func() : void {query}`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is actually a little convoluted, for example:

```
<< query >> -fnc()
```

The const can be represented as a stereotype (e.g., << query >> or «query» if you have a post-1980s computer )

Comment: Though if executing the behaviour `fnc` leaves the state of the system unchanged, and being `void` returns no value, does it really happen?

Comment: @Pete yes this fnc writes a log.

Comment: Well, it's not so much the syntax. In the abstract syntax of UML, your just setting the flag that this function is a side-effect query, so the guillemots are just eye-candy in the textual representation.

Answer (score 0):

If your function has side-effects like writing a log-file, it is not a query in the UML-sense. From the "UML Superstructure 2.3", Sec. 7.3.36 "Operation":

> isQuery : Boolean Specifies whether an execution of the BehavioralFeature leaves the state of the system unchanged (isQuery=true) or whether side effects may occur (isQuery=false). The default value is false.

Comment: That would depend on what "the system" is supposed to be. I would assume it refers to the software being described, in which case it would be appropriate to use here.